# Terminal does not open in Ubuntu 16.04 with CTRL-ALT-T

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and for some unknown reason I am not able to open a terminal with CTRL + ALT + T. When I press these keys, nothing happens.

I also tried to start a terminal from Dash, but again nothing happens.

I never had a problem opening a terminal, opened it hundreds of times before with CTRL + ALT + T.

Luckily, I am able to open a terminal by using right-click and choosing "open Terminal". But why can't I open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T anymore?

The Shortcut is still there (Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts).

Comment: `E: Package 'x-terminal-emulator' has no installation candidate` ;-)

Comment: I have not installed any special terminal, I am using the default terminal I guess. Seems to be `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Yes tried that, no affect. CTRL-ALT-T and Dash still does not work. Maybe there is a date limitation hardcoded somewhere

Comment: Alt-F2: I get an application (looks like a map, not the standard terminal icon), clicking on it does nothing. Re-adding the shortcut: No effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96198/discussion-between-alex-and-joshua-besneatte).

Comment: I am in chat now... I am going to clean up my comments... I should have a solution for you soon :)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Install / Reinstall Gnome Terminal**

First we have to determine what the default terminal command is, so let's see what terminal(s) we have installed:

```
$ apt list --installed |grep -i terminal
```

On default 16.04 you should have `gnome-terminal` installed. If it is not installed, install it:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

If it is installed, purge and reinstall it:

```
$ sudo apt purge gnome-terminal 
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt autoclean
$ sudo apt install gnome-terminal
```

Now let's make sure it's set properly:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Which should return something like this:

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

It should be set to the first entry (0), if not set it to `0`.

Confirm that your gnome-terminal.wrapper works by running it:

```
$ gnome-terminal.wrapper
```

If your terminal wrapper is broken, let me know and I will post a copy of mine or just skip to step 3.

Test your key combo, if it works, you're done! If not read on...

**2. Sometimes keyboard shortcuts need to be manually reset.**

Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Launchers` and click on the line that says "Launch terminal". Where it once said the key command, it will now say "New accelerator...", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

[image: Keyboard Shortcut Update]

Test this new macro (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and see if it works. If it doesn't work, move on to the next step. If it does work, click on the terminal line again and set it back to the original macro: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Now test your shortcut and see if it works. If it *still* doesn't work, we can make a custom shortcut to launch gnome-terminal.

**3. Custom Shortcut to Launch gnome-terminal**

Set the default terminal launcher to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> as described above so it doesn't interfere with our new command.

Now click the plus (+) button at the bottom of the list to add a new item. Call the item "Terminal" with the command `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` and click apply.

[image: Add new shortcut]

You should now have a menu item that looks like this:

[image: Terminal Disabled]

Click on the word disabled and set the shortcut by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Test your shortcut. If it *still* doesn't work, something must be wrong with your keyboard or keyboard settings. Make sure your language support and text entry settings are correct for your default language and keyboard and try setting an entirely new key combo and see if that works.

Comment: The step with the terminal wrapper does not work for me. Btw when trying to re install gnome-terminal there have been errors: Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 ubuntu-desktop
 ubuntu-desktop-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
was an output for sudo apt purge gnome-terminal for example. In the commands before and after that there have been similar errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a Xfce desktop? If so, go to Settings Manager-->Keyboard>Application Shortcuts> +Add a Terminal shortcut using this file:

```
/usr/bin/lxterminal
```

This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04

```
~$ inxi -S # to show your desktop version run this cmd at CLI
```

My  version is

```
System:    Host: <user> Kernel: 5.0.0 x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
```